# Graph API Subscription Notification Fires Continuously

Tags: onedrive

I am creating subscriptions to a OneDrive folder using the Graph API and I am receiving change notifications continuously (every half a second) even when the contents of the folder (or even the drive itself) is not changing. (Obviously I was expecting that I would receive notifications only when the folder contents change).

I post the following JSON to create the subscription:-

```
{
  "clientState": "GraphAPITest1 2018/05/01 11:31:26",
  "notificationUrl": "https://123e7ff5.ngrok.io/notification/listen",
  "resource": "/drives/b!X5kF-EHEkECCcjyJ3Fh1CTQI-5nOBktJv57zZdpp13CPQb_8FIV-RIPt-7fnzyxP/root",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-05-02T11:31:26.0881202+01:00",
  "changeType": "updated"
}
```

The notification that my service receives is:-

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "subscriptionId": "2467af01-a616-4493-8947-220146c4828a",
            "clientState": "GraphAPITest1 2018/05/01 11:23:13",
            "resource": "/drives/b!X5kF-EHEkECCcjyJ3Fh1CTQI-5nOBktJv57zZdpp13CPQb_8FIV-RIPt-7fnzyxP/root",
            "resourceData": null,
            "changeType": "updated",
            "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2018-05-02T10:23:13.3640899+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the same behaviour in my own code as well as in Microsoft's example app (https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-webhooks-aspnet). My code uses an app-only authentication token but the Microsoft example forces user authentication - both suffer from the same behaviour.

Any idea what I need to do to only get notifications when the contents of the folder actually changes?

Barry

Comment: Which url are you posting the JSON to for subscription?

Comment: In my own code I post to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions. The Microsoft example posts to https://OurName-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me/drive/root/subscriptions.

Comment: The solution was to deploy to Azure. I was using ngrok to redirect from a public URL to localhost on my development machine. Everything appeared to be working fine but I now believe that the HTTP 200 response was never getting back to the server. Unfortunately I couldn't find a firewall setting that confirmed this.